# How to export constant based on size of table

Tags: c

I have a library function which takes a single `level` parameter, and uses that to index into an array of parameter values, which I'm abstracting away from the consumer of the function.  Note that the parameter table, and even its structure type are visible only to their containing C file.

**library.h**

```
#define MIN_LEVEL   0
#define MAX_LEVEL   ((sizeof(m_param_table)/sizeof(m_param_table[0]))-1)

BOOL set_param_level(int level);
```

**library.c**

```
#include "library.h"

typedef struct {
   int param1;
   int param2;
} params_t;

// Parameters table - static (local) to this C file
static params_t m_param_table[] = {
   {0, 1},
   {2, 3},
};

BOOL set_param_level(int level) {
   int p1, p2;

   // bounds checking on MIN_LEVEL and MAX_LEVEL
   if (level < MIN_LEVEL) return FALSE;
   if (level > MAX_LEVEL) return FALSE;

   p1 = m_param_table[level].param1;
   p2 = m_param_table[level].param2;

   // do stuff with p1, p2

   return TRUE;
}
```

**consumer.c**

```
#include "library.h"

// Limit user input to MIN_LEVEL and MAX_LEVEL

set_param_level( user_input_value );
```

I would like consumer.c to be able to have access to `MIN_LEVEL` and `MAX_LEVEL`, for user-input verification. Obviously though, he doesn't have access to `m_param_table`, so those macros don't work.

What is the most elegant and *correct* way to do this?  Options are:

1) Move `typedef ... params_t` to a header file, and remove `static` from `m_params_table`. Obviously I don't like this because it makes those things unnecessarily visible.

2) Hard-code the values in a header file. Of course hard-coded values suck.

Comment: My first reaction was to use an `extern size_t MAX_LEVEL;` in the header, and define it as a variable in the .c file after the table, but I'm guessing that you've already thought of it.

Comment: @WhozCraig And it's not read-only...

Comment: Admittedly i've not tried, and have a suspicion I'm about to be schooled, but extern const size_t ... on the decl and const size_t ... on the def? The latter would be for your libs benefit only, if this is a standard symbol export `_MAX_LEVEL`, but at least the decl in the header would still proclaim `const` for the consumer-side restriction.

Comment: If the concern about being read-only is that your users can mess up your library by changing it, you could always define two sets of constants to the same values, one set `static` and internal to your library and beyond the reach of the user, and the other `extern` and available. If the issue is the user being able to mess themselves up by changing it, they can always do that by just ignoring those variables/macros and substituting their own random values.

Comment: I wish I would have worded this "as a compile time constant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want your values to be constants and at the same time you'd prefer to keep the table and the associated type declaration hidden, then one solution would be to indeed hardcode the values, but at the same time add a static assertion inside the `.c` file that will ensure that the hardcoded values are always up-to-date.

So, in the header file you do

```
#define MIN_LEVEL   0
#define MAX_LEVEL   1
```

while in the `.c` file you do

```
static params_t m_param_table[] = {
   {0, 1},
   {2, 3},
};

STATIC_ASSERT(MIN_LEVEL == 0);
STATIC_ASSERT(MAX_LEVEL == sizeof m_param_table / sizeof *m_param_table - 1);
```

(use your favorite implementation of `STATIC_ASSERT` in C).

This approach eliminates one of the most important reasons hardcoded values suck: their propensity to quietly become outdated.

Comment: While the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18560908/119527) was very good, this allows for a compile-time question, which I was going after, even though I failed to explicitly mention it.

Answer (score 5):

You have a third option:

Move `MIN_LEVEL` and `MAX_LEVEL` to `library.c` and create new functions `get_min_level()` and `get_max_level()` declared in `library.h` and implemented in `library.c` that simply return `MIN_LEVEL` and `MAX_LEVEL` respectively. These functions will be visible from `consumer.c` without revealing the library's internal data structures.

Comment: That dawned on me as I was writing the question. It seemed a bit overkill to add a function call, considering this is for an embedded project, but I'm probably worrying too much about that.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Such functions are a pretty standard data hiding idiom in C, don't worry about them being overkill. The only downside of `get_max_level()` in comparison to `MAX_LEVEL` is that the former is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: Right, that was the reason for my reluctance, but I don't think it's too much of a concern. I supposed a cross-module optimizing linker could optimize out the function call, and just insert the constant value. Shame you have to hope for that behavior though.

Comment: Rather than adding `get_max_level()` and `get_min_level()` functions, you could also just write an overall `validate_input()` function, which would not only reduce the number of function calls by one, but save your user from writing their own validation code, and they wouldn't need access to the values at all. If there's more than one input, they'd probably end up writing their own validation function anyway, so probably wouldn't cost anything additional.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: added const keywords

One option is to use externs.

First of, MIN_LEVEL and MAX_LEVEL should not be in library.h, but rather in library.c. As you have pointed out, this header file is not usable by consumers without the definitions of m_param_table. And you shouldn't have to make that public just to provide access to these constants. Here's what you can do.

In library.h:

```
extern const int min_level;
extern const int max_level;

BOOL set_param_level(int level);
```

In library.c:

```
...

#define MIN_LEVEL   0
#define MAX_LEVEL   ((sizeof(m_param_table)/sizeof(m_param_table[0]))-1)

const int min_level = MIN_LEVEL;
const int max_level = MAX_LEVEL;
```

This makes the constants available to consumers without exposing the private internals.

Comment: Except they're not at all "constants".

Comment: True enough. But it's one way of exporting constant values without exposing the private internals of a implementation. Other option is to add a validation function to the API.

Comment: Oh, I neglected to mention, you can use the "const" keyword to get constness. You would need to use it in both the header and the code. It's still not a compile time constant (requires memory access), but it a way.

Comment: Unfortunately, `const` values in C have very limited applicability. You can't use them to declare array sizes, for example (unless you are happy with a VLA), you can't use them to declared bit-fields width and so on. Such values are not constants, and that is not a good thing.